# Submitting a form to multiple URLs

Tags: html, forms

I am currently trying to learn html and wanted to create something as I was learning.  I am trying to create a search box which would retrieve results from multiple sites.  So far only the first site that is in action works but not the second one. I tried searching a lot on google but was unable to find anything, I also tried checking here but did not seem to find anything.  I am only trying to have the search box get results from multiple different sites.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Search for a Domain or IP</h1>
        <form method="get" action="https://www.virustotal.com/en/domain/%s/information/","https://duckduckgo.com/search.html?prefill=Search DuckDuckGo" target="_blank" onsubmit="submitSearch()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
        <input type="button" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are going to put a down point in this, at least let me know why.

Answer (score 1):

It's not explicitly stated [in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-action), but you can only have a single URL for the `action` attribute. To have a single form send a query to two or more websites, you have a couple of choices:

- Make the form send the query to your own page that then opens windows for each website you want to send users to. You would need to use code (i.e. not just HTML) for this.
- Add JavaScript to the form submission, so that when the user clicks the `Search` button, a window opens for each website you want to send users to. There's a related question here: [submit to multiple urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256435/submit-to-multiple-urls)